# Flutter: best timer approaches

Tags: flutter

I've been reading about different approaches when creating countdowns and I'm not sure about the best one. For my case I have 2 different timers: a countdown from 3 to 0 and a timer from 0 to 10 (that the user can pause).
These are what I tried:

**Animation**: I have this one working but I don't understand why I'd need an animation builder to have a text that I could update using `setState`.

```
    TweenAnimationBuilder<Duration>(
               duration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
               tween: Tween(
                   begin: const Duration(seconds: 0), end: const Duration(seconds: 10)),
               onEnd: () {},
```

**Timer**: this seems to be the most used, but when working with milliseconds, it's not triggering the timer in the right moment.

```
Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
      (Timer timer) {
        if (start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
```

**Stopwatch**: this calculates the exact time between 2 moments but I don't see how can I use it for my example:

```
    final stopwatch = Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.stop();
    print(stopwatch.isRunning); // false
    Duration elapsed = stopwatch.elapsed;
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    assert(stopwatch.elapsed == elapsed); // No measured time elapsed.
    stopwatch.start();
```

More info about the last 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72563318/4858133

Answer (score 1):

there is a class `Ticker` which can listen to screen frame rate. And you also dont need any animation builder just can use `setState()`, its sync almost perfectly with ui, and consistent. maybe its will suit in your need.

we can get our ticker directly from flutter 'vertical sync' (`SingSingleTickerProviderStateMixin`)

```
class _TImerState extends State<TImer> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final Ticker _ticker;
  late Duration _elapsed;
  late Duration _cachedElapsed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cachedElapsed = Duration.zero;
    _ticker = createTicker((elapsed) {
      setState(() {
        _elapsed = elapsed;
      });
    });
  }

  void _start(){
    _ticker.start();
    _cachedElapsed += _elapsed;
  }

  void _pause(){
    _ticker.stop();
  }

  void _reset(){
    _pause();
    setState(() {
      _cachedElapsed = _elapsed = Duration.zero;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.dispose();
    super.dispose();

  }
```

update: i provide the example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late ValueNotifier<Duration> _elapsed;
  late Duration _cached;
  late final Ticker _ticker;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cached = Duration.zero;
    _elapsed = ValueNotifier(Duration.zero);
    _ticker = createTicker((elapsed) {
      _elapsed.value = elapsed;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _ticker.dispose();
    _elapsed.dispose();
  }

  void _start() {
    _ticker.start();
  }

  void _pause() {
    _ticker.stop();
    _cached += _elapsed.value;
    _elapsed.value = Duration.zero;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _reset() {
    _pause();
    _elapsed.value = _cached = Duration.zero;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: _elapsed,
              builder: (context, elapsed, _) {
                return Text(
                  (elapsed + _cached).toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _elapsed,
                builder: (_, value, __) => TextButton(
                    onPressed: _ticker.isActive ? _pause : _start,
                    child: Text(_ticker.isActive ? "pause" : "start")),
              ),
              TextButton(onPressed: _reset, child: const Text("reset")),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: fantastic, another way haha. I don't really understand this one: "Creates a ticker with the given callback. The kind of ticker provided depends on the kind of ticker provider." What's the advantage from using StopWatch()? I guess it's using this method internally?

Comment: isn't this a method to run on every frame?

Comment: i dont check `StopWatch()` yet,  right know i answer with a phone,  but in case you need to perfectly sync with the device screen at least your user will see actual time. imagine if there is a jaggy (lag, maybe in millis) and the text on your ui(render the duration) will miss the actual duration. this class solve that problem. to performance gain, i assume your widget will have a lot of expensive widgets, instead of setState you can use `ValueNotifier(Duration)`, and wrap the widget you want to change and react every frame into this duration with `ValueListenableBuilder` + `RepaintBoundary`

Comment: I got this error after calling start from button: "LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_elapsed@425057491' has not been initialized.)"

Comment: _elapsed is initialized when the `_ticker.start();` called. if you want to read if before that, just initilaze in init state with empty Duration `_elapsed = Duration.zero`

Comment: I know it's initialized in initState but even with that, after adding the start/pause button (only thing I added) it throws that error:
"LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_elapsed@25057491' has not been initialized.)"

Comment: i update my answer, you can copy and paste and tweak it, i test it. its working fine

Comment: BTW, how could I detect when timer reaches a specific time like I did with the Timer solution? Because in this solution it also uses AnimationController as I mentioned in approach 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474231/flutter-perform-an-action-when-a-countdown-timer-reaches-0

Comment: inside the createTicker when initializing I could check the value but not sure if there is a better way

Comment: I don't see the way to stop it at any specific time automaticaly